# Codeigniter CSRF protection with datatables ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and we have enabled CSRF protection,

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

We have used :

```
`<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">`
```

in the form submission and its working fine,

But my application also use DataTables to get server data with AJAX,

```
var handleDataTable = function () {
    var table = $('#my_table').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
          "url" : baseURL + "user/core/data/"+report_id,
          "dataType" : "json",
          "type" : "POST", // ajax source
        },
    });
}
```

Obviously this will show "`The action you have requested is not allowed.`" message,

How can i pass csrf in Ajax retrieving data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as a header in your Ajax function :

```
var handleDataTable = function () {

    var table = $('#my_table').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
          "url" : baseURL + "user/core/data/"+report_id,
          "dataType" : "json",
          "type" : "POST", // ajax source
          "headers": {
            'CSRFToken': TOKEN //replace by your name/value
          }
        },
});
```

If you have many Ajax requests, you should set a global header for all of them :

```
$.ajaxSetup( {
    headers: {
        'CSRFToken': TOKEN  //replace by your name/value
    }
});
```

Or send the name/value pair as part of the data :

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: '...',
        data: function ( d ) {
            d.csrfName = csrfValue;
        }
    }
} );
```

[Source](https://datatables.net/manual/security)

Comment: thanks for info, i had added this in AJAX but i am not sure if CodeIgniter will look for both token name and hash? and if yes, i must need to pass two values as token, how can i?

Comment: I got solution now, actually token name in config and js was different, now made same and solved issue, thanks,